# Trouble importing function into Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have created a custom function in a .py file and am trying to use this in my Jupyter notebook after importing it, but I am receiving the following error:

```
def percentage_change(updated_total,updated_inflation_values):
    return ((updated_inflation_values - updated_total) / updated_inflation_values) * 100
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

I am not sure how I can fix this,

Thank you

Comment: What are the inputs to `percentage_change `

Comment: You are trying to subtract two strings, that just isn't supported. This can be checked via the following `'a' - 'b'`. You need to check what your input type is when calling that function

Comment: the column values in updated_total and updated_inflation_values were originally changed from str to float

Answer (score 0):

You are giving `str` inputs, that's why you are getting errors like this.
Make sure that you are providing `int` arguments.

Check the executions

```
In [74]: percentage_change(10, 100)
Out[74]: 90.0

In [75]: percentage_change('10', '100')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [75], line 1
----> 1 percentage_change('10', '100')

Cell In [73], line 2, in percentage_change(updated_total, updated_inflation_values)
      1 def percentage_change(updated_total,updated_inflation_values):
----> 2     return ((updated_inflation_values - updated_total) / updated_inflation_values) * 100

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```